# Run method never get executed

Tags: java, chat

I am currently trying to develop a simple local area network chat feature for the company. But I'm stuck at this point where the run method never get executed in client which previously working fine. It started not working after I restructure the constructor to be able to dispose and visible frame on system tray icon double click. Please let me know where I'm go wrong. I send you the code where it was previously working and current now where it's not working. I can also send the server interface source and other code if needed.

Before structuring (ChatClient.java)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import sun.audio.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class ChatClient extends Thread implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel mainPanel;
    JLabel label_1, label_2, label_3, label_4, label_5, charCnt;
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu tool, help;
    JMenuItem save, log, exit, about, information;
    JTextField field_2;
    JTextArea area_1, area_2;
    JCheckBox cb1;
    JButton button_1, button_2, button_3, button_4, button_5, button_6, button_7;
    JScrollPane scroll, scroll2;
    Icon send = new ImageIcon("Resources/Image/send.gif");
    Icon sv = new ImageIcon("Resources/Image/save.png");
    Icon lg = new ImageIcon("Resources/Image/logoff.gif");
    Icon ext = new ImageIcon("Resources/Image/exit.png");
    Icon About = new ImageIcon("Resources/Image/about.png");
    Icon clear = new ImageIcon("Resources/Image/clear.png");
    Icon info = new ImageIcon("Resources/Image/help.png");
    Font small = new Font("Sans Serif", Font.ITALIC, 9);
    String strg[] = new String[10];
    int arr, ctr2 = 0;
    int charMax = 150;
    boolean ignoreInput = false;

    JList list;
    DefaultListModel listModel;

    Color background = new Color(241, 243, 248);
    Color color = new Color(255, 255, 255);

    Socket client;

    String messageToAll, name;
    BufferedReader fromServer;
    PrintStream toServer;

    Login login;
    time2 obj2 = new time2(this);
    Thread thr = new Thread(this);

    @SuppressWarnings({"CallToThreadStartDuringObjectConstruction", "ResultOfObjectAllocationIgnored"})
    ChatClient(String name, String IP, Login login) {

        super(name);
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        }
        Image bd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Resources/Image/client.png");
        this.name = name;
        this.login = login;
        frame = new JFrame("Client - " + name);
        frame.setIconImage(bd);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        tool = new JMenu("Tools");
        help = new JMenu("Help");
        save = new JMenuItem("Save");
        log = new JMenuItem("Login as..");
        exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        about = new JMenuItem("About");
        information = new JMenuItem("Information");
        label_1 = new JLabel("Online Users");
        label_3 = new JLabel("Messages: ");
        label_4 = new JLabel("Public Message");
        label_5 = new JLabel("");
        charCnt = new JLabel("");
        field_2 = new JTextField(29);
        field_2.setToolTipText("Date & Time");
        field_2.setEditable(false);
        field_2.setFocusable(false);
        cb1 = new JCheckBox("private");
        cb1.setToolTipText("Private message");
        area_1 = new JTextArea(20, 10);
        area_1.setFont(login.notify);
        area_1.setLineWrap(true);
        area_1.setEditable(false);
        area_2 = new JTextArea(1, 10);
        area_2.setLineWrap(true);
        area_2.setToolTipText("type your message here..");
        scroll = new JScrollPane(area_1);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scroll2 = new JScrollPane(area_2);
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        listModel = new DefaultListModel();
        list = new JList(listModel);
        list.setToolTipText("Client available");

        button_1 = new JButton("SEND");
        button_1.setToolTipText("send message");

        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.add(menuBar);
        mainPanel.add(charCnt);
        mainPanel.add(label_1);
        mainPanel.add(label_3);
        mainPanel.add(label_4);
        mainPanel.add(label_5);
        mainPanel.add(field_2);
        mainPanel.add(scroll);
        mainPanel.add(scroll2);
        mainPanel.add(list);
        mainPanel.add(button_1);
        mainPanel.add(cb1);
        cb1.setFont(login.notify);
        button_1.setIcon(send);

        mainPanel.setLayout(null);
        menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 25);
        //Users
        label_1.setBounds(455, 5, 150, 20);
        //Messages Box
        //label_2.setBounds(245, 317, 150, 20);
        //Messages
        //label_3.setBounds(5, 335, 90, 25);
        //Public Messages
        label_4.setBounds(140, 5, 300, 20);
        //time
        label_5.setBounds(485, 297, 100, 25);
        //Characters count
        charCnt.setBounds(80, 360, 150, 15);
        charCnt.setFont(small);
        scroll.setBounds(5, 30, 390, 300);
        scroll2.setBounds(5, 335, 450, 35);
        list.setBounds(400, 30, 185, 260);
        field_2.setBounds(479, 300, 110, 25);
        cb1.setBounds(398, 300, 70, 20);

        //button
        button_1.setBounds(490, 336, 95, 27);

        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        button_1.addActionListener(this);
        button_1.addKeyListener(this);
        button_1.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        area_2.addKeyListener(this);
        field_2.addKeyListener(this);
        list.addKeyListener(this);
        cb1.addActionListener(this);
        cb1.addKeyListener(this);
        cb1.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_P);

        try {
            client = new Socket(IP, 1001);
            toServer = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
            fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            toServer.println("##" + name);
            thr.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            area_1.setText("no server detected!");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "      No server running! " + lineSeparator + "Sorry, You've to log out.... ");
            this.frame.dispose();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        area_2.requestFocus();
        obj2.start();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("ResultOfObjectAllocationIgnored")
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        new Login();
    }

    public void run() {
            while (thr != null) {

            try {createAndShowUI(); >>this code here executed properly.

            } catch (IOException | HeadlessException e) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server has Closed!" + lineSeparator + "Sorry, you've to log out");
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
        }
```

After restructuring (ChatClient.java)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import sun.audio.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public final class ChatClient extends Thread implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    JPanel mainPanel;
    JLabel label_1, label_2, label_3, label_4, label_5, charCnt;
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu tool, help;
    JMenuItem save, log, exit, about, information;
    JTextField field_2;
    JTextArea area_2;
    JTextPane chatPane;
    JCheckBox cb1;
    JButton button_1, button_2, button_3, button_4, button_5, button_6, button_7;
    JScrollPane scroll, scroll2, scroll3;
    Icon send = new ImageIcon("Resources/Image/send.gif");
    Icon sv = new ImageIcon("Resources/Image/save.png");
    Icon lg = new ImageIcon("Resources/Image/logoff.gif");
    Icon ext = new ImageIcon("Resources/Image/exit.png");
    Icon About = new ImageIcon("Resources/Image/about.png");
    Icon clear = new ImageIcon("Resources/Image/clear.png");
    Icon info = new ImageIcon("Resources/Image/help.png");
    Font small = new Font("Sans Serif", Font.ITALIC, 9);
    Font prv = new Font("Helvetica", Font.ITALIC, 14);
    String strg[] = new String[10];
    int arr, ctr2 = 0;
    int charMax = 150;
    boolean ignoreInput = false;

    JList list;
    DefaultListModel listModel;

    Color background = new Color(241, 243, 248);
    Color color = new Color(255, 255, 255);

    Socket client;

    String messageToAll, name;
    BufferedReader fromServer;
    PrintStream toServer;

    Login login;
    time2 obj2 = new time2(this);
    Thread thr = new Thread(this);

    /**
     *
     * @param name
     * @param IP
     * @param login
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({"CallToThreadStartDuringObjectConstruction", "ResultOfObjectAllocationIgnored"})

    public ChatClient(String name, String IP, Login login) {

        super(name);
        try {
            createAndShowUI(name);
            createAndShowGUI(name);
            client = new Socket(IP, 1001);
            toServer = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
            fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            toServer.println("##" + name);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            chatPane.setText("no server detected!");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "      No server running! " + lineSeparator + "Sorry, You've to log out.... ");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public ChatClient() {
//        defaultItem1.addActionListener(exitListener);
//        defaultItem2.addActionListener(restoreListener);
//        this.login = login;
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        }
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        tool = new JMenu("Tools");
        help = new JMenu("Help");
        save = new JMenuItem("Save");
        log = new JMenuItem("Login as..");
        exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        about = new JMenuItem("About");
        information = new JMenuItem("Information");
        label_1 = new JLabel("Online Users");
        label_3 = new JLabel("Messages: ");
        label_4 = new JLabel("Public Message");
        label_5 = new JLabel("");
        charCnt = new JLabel("");
        field_2 = new JTextField(29);
        field_2.setToolTipText("Date & Time");
        field_2.setEditable(false);
        field_2.setFocusable(false);
        cb1 = new JCheckBox("private");
        cb1.setToolTipText("Private message");
        chatPane = new JTextPane();
        area_2 = new JTextArea(1, 10);
        area_2.setLineWrap(true);
        area_2.setToolTipText("type your message here..");
        listModel = new DefaultListModel();
        list = new JList(listModel);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        list.setToolTipText("Client available");
        list.setVisibleRowCount(5);
        scroll = new JScrollPane(chatPane);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scroll2 = new JScrollPane(area_2);
        scroll2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scroll2.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scroll3 = new JScrollPane(list);
        scroll3.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scroll3.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        button_1 = new JButton("SEND");
        button_1.setToolTipText("send message");
        mainPanel.add(charCnt);
        mainPanel.add(label_1);
        mainPanel.add(label_3);
        mainPanel.add(label_4);
        mainPanel.add(label_5);
        mainPanel.add(field_2);
        mainPanel.add(scroll);
        mainPanel.add(scroll2);
        mainPanel.add(scroll3);
        mainPanel.add(button_1);
        mainPanel.add(cb1);
        cb1.setFont(prv);
        button_1.setIcon(send);

        mainPanel.setLayout(null);
        menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 25);
        //Users
        label_1.setBounds(455, 5, 150, 20);
        //Messages Box
        //label_2.setBounds(245, 317, 150, 20);
        //Messages
        //label_3.setBounds(5, 335, 90, 25);
        //Public Messages
        label_4.setBounds(140, 5, 300, 20);
        //time
        label_5.setBounds(485, 297, 100, 25);
        //Characters count
        charCnt.setBounds(380, 358, 120, 15);
        charCnt.setFont(small);
        scroll.setBounds(5, 25, 390, 300);
        //chatPane.setFocusable(false);
        chatPane.setEditable(false);
        scroll2.setBounds(5, 325, 485, 48);
        scroll3.setBounds(400, 30, 185, 260);

        field_2.setBounds(477, 300, 112, 25);
        cb1.setBounds(398, 300, 70, 20);

        button_1.setBounds(490, 326, 100, 30);

        button_1.addActionListener(this);
        button_1.addKeyListener(this);
        button_1.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        area_2.addKeyListener(this);
        field_2.addKeyListener(this);
        list.addKeyListener(this);
        cb1.addActionListener(this);
        cb1.addKeyListener(this);
        cb1.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_P);

        try {
            thr.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        area_2.requestFocus(true);
        obj2.start();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("ResultOfObjectAllocationIgnored")
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        new Login();
    }
    public void run() {
        while (thr != null) {
            try {
                createAndShowUI(); >> this code never run to
```

Login.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

final class Login {

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel label_1, label_2, label_3, label_4;
    JTextField field_1, field_2;
    JPasswordField pass;
    JButton button_1, button_2;
    Font Default = new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    Font notify = new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 12);
    Font small = new Font("Sans Serif", Font.ITALIC, 3);
    //String IP;
    Socket client;
    InetAddress ipaddr;
    String hostname;

    PrintStream toServer;

    ChatClient clientObj;

    public String gethostString(){
        try {
            ipaddr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            hostname = ipaddr.getHostName();
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        }
        return hostname;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("CallToPrintStackTrace")
    Login() {
        String IP = "192.168.10.88";
        try {
            ipaddr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            hostname = ipaddr.getHostName();
            clientObj = new ChatClient(gethostString(), IP, this);
//            clientObj.createAndShowGUI(hostname);
//            clientObj.createAndShowUI();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Image bd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Image/login.png");
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

This is my method createAndShowUI.

```
public void createAndShowUI(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        JFrame frame;
        frame = new JFrame("Client - " + name);
        Image bd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Resources/Image/client.png");
        frame.setIconImage(bd);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new ChatClient().mainPanel); >> I call the constructor here to draw the frame.
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setResizable(false);
//        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JComponent getComponent() {
        return mainPanel;
    }
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Where is login class, and what you are doing in Login() constructor. As, you have to start thread inside Login() for execution of run.

Comment: Okay, I have added the login.java. And I call ChatClient object inside it's constructor. I will try to upload the server and other class needed for you to get it running. Thanks for your reply anyway. Cheers!

Comment: I was trying to share the server source with you guys but the first post doesn't allow me to post more than 30000 characters. I need another 5000 characters for the server and other classes. Do we have other options or way to share it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code using a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a second no-argument constructor, and nobody is invoking that second constructor. However, you moved the code that starts the thread into that second constructor, so now the thread is not being started anymore().

Perhaps you want to call this method `public void init() {` instead of `public ChatClient() {`, and then you call `init();` at the end of the first constructor that has 3 arguments.

Comment: Dear Bolwidt,

Thank you very much for your fast response. I have tried to put the run method inside 3 arguments constructor at first and even main method but no luck. I have tried as you suggested and it actually solves the issue! Run method executed now. But the other problem now I can't have my frame running well, I actually created method to draw frame because I need to recall it on system tray icon double click as I mentioned below. I would like to share the snippet to you. Hopefully I can still post the snippet in the first post. Please help me. Thank you again! you're my angel.

Comment: @RaymondNatio If this solved the problem, then you should accept the answer. If you uncover new problems, you should first try to solve them yourself, and otherwise post a new question.

Comment: Okay @MarkRotteveel thank you for your advice. I will try to solve it first if not lucky I will post a new question by tomorrow afternoon. Thanks again. Cheers.